# Can't find installed module on modulepath

Tags: puppet, vagrant, rvm

I'm attempting to use the [maestrodev/rvm](https://github.com/maestrodev/puppet-rvm) module when provisioning a virtual machine with Vagrant, but am running into a problem when attempting to `include rvm`. I keep getting

```
Error: Could not find class rvm for vagrant-ubuntu-saucy-64 on node vagrant-ubuntu-saucy-64
Error: Could not find class rvm for vagrant-ubuntu-saucy-64 on node vagrant-ubuntu-saucy-64
```

I see the same error twice, and I see it before any other output. I have installed the module using

```
puppet module install maestrodev/rvm
```

and after running this command the output of `puppet config print modulepath` yields

```
/home/notgary/.puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules
```

while `puppet module list` yields

```
/home/notgary/.puppet/modules
├── maestrodev-rvm (v1.2.0)
├── puppetlabs-apache (v0.9.0)
├── puppetlabs-concat (v1.0.0)
└── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.1.0)
/usr/share/puppet/modules (no modules installed)
```

The above output reveals the module (the first entry in the list) to be installed in `~/.puppet/modules` and the output above that reveals that this directory is included in the `modulepath`. Unless I am misunderstanding the what this means, I would expect `include rvm` to install rvm in `/usr/local/rvm`, as stated in the documentation, but when the puppet compiler hits that line, I get the error message mentioned at the top of this post.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What about if you run `sudo puppet module list`?

Comment: What is the value for modulepath in /etc/puppet/puppet.conf ?

Answer (score 1):

By default puppet looks for modules in *$confdir/modules* and */usr/share/puppet/modules*.

```
$ sudo puppet config print modulepath
/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules
```

This does not include *$HOME/.puppet*, but that's where you installed the module. Install the modules as root, or change the modulepath in *$confdir/puppet.conf*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I've got it installed in both `/etc/puppet/modules` and `~/.puppet/modules`, but it's still not getting picked up.